# ROC in R with an averaged model

Tags: r, model, roc

I can't get ROC from the pROC package in R to accept an averaged model. I assume it has something to do with how the model is being stored from model. I used model.ave to create the averaged model (just like all of the examples I have been able to find.

In the code I show an example of it working correctly with an unaveraged model, and then the error with the averaged model:

```
> m5.roc <- roc(idle$Used, predict(idle.structure.model.quad, backtransform = TRUE, smooth=TRUE))
> rs5<-smooth(m5.roc)
> plot(m5.roc, type="l")

Call:
roc.default(response = idle$Used, predictor = predict(idle.structure.model.quad,     backtransform = TRUE, smooth = TRUE))

Data: predict(idle.structure.model.quad, backtransform = TRUE, smooth = TRUE) in 42 controls (idle$Used 0) < 41 cases (idle$Used 1).
Area under the curve: 0.8362
> lines(rs5, type="l", lty=3)
> m3.roc <- roc(idle$Used, predict(idle.final, backtransform = TRUE, smooth=TRUE))
Error in roc.default(idle$Used, predict(idle.final, backtransform = TRUE,  : 
  No valid data provided.
```

Any ideas would be helpful. Thanks